# sddm shows a black screen only

Tags: arch-linux, plasma5, sddm

I'm new to Arch Linux and wanted to use the plasma 5 desktop with sddm.
I'm able to start the plasma desktop via `startx` without any issues but when I try to use sddm it only shows me a black screen on startup.

I tried to restart the sddm service with `systemctl restart sddm` but it remains black.

When I run `sddm-greeter --test-mode --theme /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze`it shows the greeter screen but I can't get it to run on startup.

My `/etc/sddm.config` looks like this:

```
[Autologin]
Relogin=false
Session=
User=

[General]
HaltCommand=
RebootCommand=

[Theme]
Current=breeze
CursorTheme=breeze_cursors

[Users]
MaximumUid=65000
MinimumUid=1000
```

And `journalctl -b --unit=sddm.service` gives me the following output

```
Jan 13 11:04:15 dev systemd[1]: Started Simple Desktop Display Manager.
Jan 13 11:04:15 dev sddm[855]: Initializing...
Jan 13 11:04:15 dev sddm[855]: Logind interface found
Jan 13 11:04:15 dev sddm[855]: Starting...
Jan 13 11:04:15 dev sddm[855]: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
Jan 13 11:04:15 dev sddm[855]: Loading theme configuration from ""
Jan 13 11:04:15 dev sddm[855]: Display server starting...
Jan 13 11:04:15 dev sddm[855]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{af3bc692-6770-441f-9c28-
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Setting default cursor
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Running display setup script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup"
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Display server started.
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Socket server starting...
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Socket server started.
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Loading theme configuration from ""
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Greeter starting...
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{af3bc692-6770-441f-9c28-2eb05f1d0ede}"
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm-helper[869]: [PAM] Starting...
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm-helper[869]: [PAM] Authenticating...
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm-helper[869]: [PAM] returning.
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm-helper[869]: pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session opened for user sddm by (uid=0)
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Greeter session started successfully
Jan 13 11:04:18 dev sddm[855]: Message received from greeter: Connect
```

Comment: Are you using NVidia+Intel hybrid graphics? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#SDDM fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why Elmo Todurov wrote a comment instead of an answer, but it was indeed the only working solution for me and therefore an answer.

edit the file: /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup

prepend the following lines:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i had the same problems for hours